# Is it possible a multiple web application containers be hosted in a single NGINX container?

Tags: linux, docker, nginx

I'm totally new in this topic, I will explain what I want to do.

```
              +-------+
    +---------+ NGINX +-----------+
    |         +-------+           |
    |                 |           |
+---+----+            |           |
|JENKINS |       +----+----+ +----+---+
+--------+       |FLASK APP| | VUE APP|
                 +---------+ +--------+
```

Creating a new server I've decided to organize and work with better tools to help make a better dev each day. My idea is this point is use a Jenkins to help a deploy my apps, above I gave a example of *Flask (PYTHON)* and *Vue (JS)*, but I'm picturing severals apps.

`NGINX` is dockerize, what is correct? dockerize all this applications *(FLASK, JENKINS, VUE)* or only the WebServer?

I've read once that is possible make multiple containers communicate among them, but I don't know if it fits in that idea

Comment: That is my question, this can be turn four containers or just one containers, I don't know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *can* put whatever you want in a container, but you *should* have one and only one process in them. When I look at that diagram I see four containers and, possibly, a Docker Compose or Kubernetes config to spin them up properly and in the correct order.

Due to the way containers work, if the primary process fails the health check the whole thing gets terminated and rebooted. This could be highly disruptive if 3/4 of your services are operating properly.

It also complicates:

- Building containers as now your container is 4x as huge as it needs to be, which makes starting, stopping, pulling and pushing slower
- The whole container must be rebuilt each time any line of code in any of those apps changes, meaning you'll need to build more often
- Rolling back a part of it is impossible with a unified container unless you rebuild a container with the particular versions necessary

In short, don't do it. Have four small containers.